# Must an employer pay a living wage

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, employment

In the USA many employees can’t afford to see a doctor because of the many bills, yet their employers are rich.

Are there sources in Judaism that require that an employer must provide for an employee to live above poverty (however defined)?

Comment: When it comes to monetary halacha 2 counterparts can usually halachically agree on anything. This employee knew what hetshe is getting into when accepting the Job and as such accepted those terms, why then should the employer have to pay more? Not sure how the employer being rich has anything to do with the question

Comment: Slavery is legal in halacha.

Comment: @Yoreinu The should is obvious to any human. It's the must he's asking about.

Comment: @DoubleAA you are speaking in riddles

Comment: I’m asking if an employer has to pay a living wage. And yes of course it matters if he’s rich, if the person is starving then how would it be ethical to not pay more?

Comment: @RaulValdezJr. An individual can choose to be as generous and benevolent as they want, or the opposite. At the end of the day, all stand before the Heavenly Court for judgement. Like is mentioned in the Talmud, one of the first questions posed is how one conducted themselves in business. We are told generally to “walk in His ways”. G-d provides fully for all of His creation and no one can hide from the Faithful King and True Judge.

Comment: Still not a halachic answer

Comment: Most people who don't earn enough in the US are eligible for either State insurance plans or Obamacare. So I'm not sure if your first sentence is accurate.

Comment: Also how would a living wage be determined?

Comment: There is no concept of a living wage for an employee in Halacha. There is a concept of leaving a debtor with basic living materials, there is a concept of contemporary living standards in charity, but not for employees

Comment: With respect to giving charity, the amount we give a person is related to the standard of living a person to which the recipient is accustomed. Perhaps there is a related concept for wages.

Comment: If someone can't earn enough to live on, the community is required to provide for him as charity. The person's employer may also be required to give charity to those in need, including his employee who isn't earning enough to live on. However, there is no requirement to pay any specific amount as wages, except for whatever was agreed upon at the start of the employment.